# rviz increase network traffic on lo interface

Tags: rviz, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there,

I have a robot with Velodyn 32E installed. This laser outputs data at around 18Mbps. In my configuration, the robot is configured as ROS master, a base station computer is configured as a client. When I start the launch file to launch the velodyne laser driver node at the robot side, I also run the rviz at my base station side. Now, I have an interesting observation, once I start rviz, even without subscribe to anything, the loopback (lo) network interface at my base station computer shoots up to 18Mbps. What happened here?   Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**:

```
<launch> 
  <arg name="pcap" default=""/> 
  <arg name="calibration" default="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/params/32db.yaml"/> 
  <include file="$(find velodyne_driver)/launch/nodelet_manager.launch"> 
    <arg name="model" value="32E"/> 
    <arg name="pcap" value="$(arg pcap)"/> 
  </include> 
  <include file="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/launch/cloud_nodelet.launch"> 
    <arg name="calibration" value="$(arg calibration)"/> 
  </include> 
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76072/rviz-increase-network-traffic-on-lo-interface/) by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-03**:
Are you running the node or nodelet versions of the driver and pointcloud conversion packages?

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-09-03**:
I am running the nodelet from the velodyne driver package.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-03**:
Please update your question to add the launch script you use.

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-09-04**:
I simply run the sample launch file,

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-04**:
What version of the driver are you running? What ROS distro?

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-09-04**:
ROS is fuerte, Ubuntu12.04. I installed the stack by running sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-velodyne

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-04**:
Since you are running velodyne_driver and velodyne_pointcloud on the same nodelet manager process, I would not expect that to generate loopback traffic by itself. Once rviz subscribes, the extra traffic makes sense. Is rviz already subscribed due to an earlier invocation?

**Comment by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on 2013-09-04**:
I deleted all the rviz subscriptions and use bmon to check the lo traffic. It is still around 18 Mbps. and this slows down a lot of other coms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't yet understand what is happening. I am only writing this as an "answer" for easier formatting.

You may get some insights from running this command on the robot:

```
$ rostopic bw /velodyne_packets
```

For your 32E, I'd expect that to report about 2MB/s (bytes, not bits). But, as long as velodyne_pointcloud is the only subscriber, I would not expect that bandwidth to appear on loopback. While rostopic is running, I would.

```
$ rostopic bw /velodyne_points
```

The corresponding point cloud published by velodyne_pointcloud will be considerably larger. It should not appear on the network unless something external to the nodelet process (like rostopic or rviz) is subscribing.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0